# Django Admin: Integrity error on "save as" with GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, admin, generic-foreign-key

What I have:

a) A simple class to store tags:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    """
    Defines a tag for any model object.
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
    type = models.ForeignKey(TagType, related_name='+', verbose_name="Typ", db_column='Typ')
    value = models.CharField("Wert", max_length=80, db_column='Wert')
```

b) A mixin that adds the reverse direction to any class:

```
class TaggedMixin(models.Model):
    """ Mixed into a model class, provides it with the ability to receive tags
    (i.e. Tag objects).
    """
    _tags = GenericRelation(Tag)
```

c) And some class, call it Data, that inherits from the Mixin. In the admin, this class uses a GenericTabularInline for Tag to display the Data's tags. It also sets "save_as" to True in order to get the "Save As" button on its admin page.

What happens:
When I click "Save As" for a Data object that has at least one tag, I get:
Integrity Error (1048, "Column 'content_type_id' cannot be null")

To me it seems like Django Admin does not handle GenericForeignKeys properly when doing the "Save As". Is there a way to get it running? A way to work around the problem? Or could I be doing something wrong here?

Perhaps I should add, I am using Django 1.7.7 here.

EDIT: We have upgraded to 1.8.2 and the problem still persists. Any ideas?